# I am not understanding how my tuple index is out of range with get_node_attributes and networkx

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I am struggling with getting the below code to work. My objective is, after specifying nodes/edges with specific positions, to calculate the distance between them. When I hardcode values 0 and 1, I receive the expected answer, but when I try to iterate using a while loop, I get the following error output (EDITED to add full error message):

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Math Thinking in CS\Python code>py hamilt.py
86.6083136886985
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Math Thinking in CS\Python code\hamilt.py", line 77, in <module>
    print(cycle_length(g,cycle3))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Math Thinking in CS\Python code\hamilt.py", line 27, in cycle_length
    dist = np.sqrt(((pos[d+1][d]-pos[d][d]))**2 + (pos[d][d+1]-pos[d+1][d+1])**2)
                                                   ~~~~~~^^^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Special note - I am not using a for loop of the form "for _ in [:-1]:" because for some reason, the coursera grader I am using calls this out of range even when it works successfully on my machine. Also, the discussion forums on the class I am taking are very inactive, so I am turning elsewhere for help. Since this is for a class, feel free to point me in the direction instead of answering / directly giving code solutions if that's more instructive.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def cycle_length(g, cycle):
    assert len(cycle) == g.number_of_nodes()
    cycleweight = 0
    vertices = 0
    pos=nx.get_node_attributes(g,'pos')

    dist=range(0,len(cycle))
    d = 0
    while d < len(cycle) - 1:
        dist = np.sqrt(((pos[d+1][d]-pos[d][d]))**2 + (pos[d][d+1]-pos[d+1][d+1])**2) #this is the line giving me issues
        print(dist)
        d += 1
    
    while vertices < len(cycle) - 1:
        cycleweight = cycleweight + g[cycle[vertices]][cycle[vertices+1]]['weight']*dist[vertices]
        vertices += 1
    return cycleweight
    
g = nx.Graph()

g.add_node(0,pos=(174,25))
g.add_node(1,pos=(129,99))
g.add_node(2,pos=(268,212))
g.add_node(3,pos=(211,209))
g.add_node(4,pos=(156,82))

g.add_edge(4,1,weight=1)
g.add_edge(1,0,weight=1)
g.add_edge(0,3,weight=1)
g.add_edge(3,2,weight=1)
g.add_edge(2,4,weight=1)

cycle3 = [4,1,0,3,2]

print(cycle_length(g,cycle3))
```

I've tried inputting hardcoded values and this works, but when I try to put in a variable I am iterating, I fail to get it to work.

Comment: Show the full error message.  If the error occurs in a long line, try to break that line to pieces to better isolate which indexing is the problem .  It's also a good idea to check the `shape` of item being indexed, and display the problem index.  There's a lot of debugging that you should be able to do without help from us or your friends.

Comment: @hpaulj - thank you very much, edited to show error message. You and the other contributor both helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
    d = 0
    while d < len(cycle) - 1:
        dist = np.sqrt(((pos[d + 1][d] - pos[d][d])) ** 2 + (
                    pos[d][d + 1] - pos[d + 1][d + 1]) ** 2)
        print(dist)
        d += 1
```

With `d` starting at `0`, you keep going `while d < len(cycle) - 1`, incrementing `d` by one on every iteration. In your example, `len(cycle)` is `5`, so `d` goes from `0` to `3`.

On the second iteration, `d` equals `1`, what do you think happens when you evaluate `pos[d][d + 1]`, if `pos` has the value `{0: (174, 25), 1: (129, 99), 2: (268, 212), 3: (211, 209), 4: (156, 82)}`? What value did you expect from `(129, 99)[2]`?

The second index `y` of `pos[x][y]` should always be `0` or `1`, if you're using it to access a dictionary of 2-tuples.

Comment: oof. You got right to it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel this answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark next to it, so that your question no longer appears as unanswered.